# Pass the "in" parameter dynamically - ms sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following ms-sql query

```
select * from category where categoryId in (1)
```

Now instead of 1, I need to pass more than one categoryId dynamically using parameters. Something like this:

```
select * from category where categoryId in (@catId)
```

and value of @catId would be something like '1,2'. When I tried this I got an error saying

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

How can I pass more than one categoryId.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx), a new feature in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XML data type instead to pass a list of ID's.

```
declare @catId xml = '<i>1</i><i>2</i><i>3</i>'

select *
from category
where categoryid in (select T.N.value('.', 'int')
                     from @catId.nodes('/i') as T(N))
```